# Generic type Subject<T> requires 1 type argument(s). - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-services

I'm getting data from my service and I've red about it's important to unsubscribe after subscribe, and here is how I did it:

```js
export class RItemComponent implements OnInit {

    apiPath = environment.apiUrl;
    private ngUnsubscribe: Subject = new Subject();

    constructor(private _sharedService: SharedService) { }

    rItems: Product[];

    ngOnInit() {
    this._sharedService.
        getReceiptItem().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).
        subscribe(products => this.rItems = products);
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }
}
```

But now I'm getting an error:

```
Generic type Subject<T> requires 1 type argument(s). subscribe
```

I don't understand why?

Any kind of help would be awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `Subject` class has a generic type parameter in TypeScript. This means, that instances of this class can only be created by passing an additional type parameter, like this:

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<MyClass> = new Subject();
```

Comment: You're welcome :-) There are books written about ReactiveX, but good starting point is the following: http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html. Concerning generic type parameters, have a look at the TypeScript doc: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 18):

Add a generic type for subject

```
private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<any> = new Subject();
```

Comment: `any` is discouraged. There's almost always a more accurate type. If you really don't know or can't know what the type will be, then consider using the new type `unknown`.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type