# JWT library error: Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders<T>' requires 1 type argument(s) in Angular 10

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, jwt

For an authentication project I am using:

`Angular CLI: 11.0.4` for the frontend

`Node: 10.19.0` for the backend

`OS: linux x64`

I receive the following error after `ng serve` and I am not sure why that is happening, the error seems to be in the library **node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.d.ts** and not in the code I wrote:

> node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.d.ts:88:41 - error TS2314:
> Generic type 'ModuleWithProviders' requires 1 type argument(s).
>
> static forRoot(config: AuthConfig): ModuleWithProviders;

Also connected to that (so I believe the errors are concurrent or even, I am afraid, interchangeable), because it was shown as soon as the `'ModuleWithProviders<T>'` error was shown, so I though it would make sense to show them both as they are linked together:

> Error: node_modules/angular2-jwt/angular2-jwt.d.ts:1:77 - error
> TS2307: Cannot find module '@angular/http' or its corresponding type
> declarations.
>
> 1 import { Http, Request, RequestOptions, RequestOptionsArgs, Response
> } from "@angular/http";

So the difficulty I have is also due to the fact that I am not sure which parts of the code are affected so I will put for the sake of completeness the `app.module.ts` and the files carrying the `jwt include`

**app.module.ts**:

```
import { ValidateService } from './services/validate.service';
import { FlashMessagesModule } from 'angular2-flash-messages'; 
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service'; 
import { AuthGuard } from './guards/auth.guards';


const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {path:'', component: HomeComponent},
  {path:'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path:'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
  {path:'profile', component: ProfileComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegisterComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    ProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    FlashMessagesModule.forRoot(),
    HttpClientModule,
  ],
  providers: [ValidateService, AuthService, AuthGuard],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**auth.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { tokenNotExpired } from 'angular2-jwt';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  authToken: any;
  user: any;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  registerUser(user) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/register', user, httpOptions);
  }

  authenticateUser(user) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      })
    };
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user, httpOptions);
  }

  getProfile() {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/json',
        Authorization: this.authToken,
      })
    };
    this.loadToken();
    return this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', httpOptions);
  }

  storeUserData(token, user) {
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  loadToken() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('id_token');
    this.authToken = token;
  }

  loggedIn() {
    return tokenNotExpired();
  }

  logout() {
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

**profile.components.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';  

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.css']
})
export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {
  user: Object = {};

  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.authService.getProfile().subscribe(profile => {
      this.user = profile;
    },
    err => {
      console.log(err);
      return false;
    })
  }
}
```

I did research on how to solve the problem and here is was I was able to find so far:
[this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63078349/modulewithproviderst-requires-1-type-arguments-angular-autofocus-fix) is very useful because it has my same exact problem.
The answer calls for a [bug report repo](https://github.com/korniychuk/angular-autofocus-fix/issues/14) that, however, does not provide any answer to that.
The answer that was provided suggests to insert the following code:

```
declare module "@angular/core" {
  interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
    ngModule: Type<T>;
    providers?: Provider[];
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this was not an accepted answer and I am not sure where I can put this piece of code in any part of the **app.module.ts** I provided above.

I also studied [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51096567/generic-type-subjectt-requires-1-type-arguments-angular) which was also useful but did not use the suggestion above.
The strange fact I understand from the error is that it seems to come from the library itself and not from the code that I wrote.

Following this I proceeded with:

1. `rm -rf` all the node_modules
2. `rm -rf` the package jason file
3. clean the cache
4. `npm install`

But outcome is the same, I always receive the same error on the same library.
Please if anyone had the same problem can you share how it was solved and what should I do more to take care of that.

Answer (score 1):

Insert this piece of code into the angular2-jwt.d.ts class and confirm the class change:

```
declare module "@angular/core" {
      interface ModuleWithProviders<T = any> {
        ngModule: Type<T>;
        providers?: Provider[];
      }
    }
```

But you should use a newer library than this, like `@auth0/angular-jwt`
After installing this library, you must register its module in the class `app.module.ts` :

```
  import {JwtModule} from '@auth0/angular-jwt'


  imports: [
     JwtModule.forRoot({
        config: {
          tokenGetter:() => {
             return localStorage.getItem('access_token'); 
          },
        },
     })
  ],
```

And then you can use it in your AuthService class:

```
 import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

 constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) {
   }

 isAuthenticated(): boolean {
    return !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(this.token);
  }
```

All this is explained in a short documentation with examples (`https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt`), so don't be lazy to read it before using any library.